# Buscar un objeto en una lista de objetos C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un objeto:
`Persona persona = new Persona("Qwerty", 22);`

También tengo una lista de personas que ya tiene personas, incluida al objeto de arriba:
`List<Persona> ListaPersonas = new List<Persona>();`

Pero cuando lo trato de buscar de esta manera:
`ListaPersonas.Contains(persona);`

Obtengo un false. Y debería obtener true.

Answer (score 3):

El Contains de una lista pregunta por un objeto que sea igual al argumento ingresado. Entonces la pregunta de fondo es: cuando un objeto es igual a otro??

Para los objetos derivados de una clase, son iguales cuando referencian al mismo espacio en memoria. (esto es parecido el típico problema de pasar por referencia o por valor)

Ejemplo

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Persona p1 = new("persona1", 1);
            Persona p2 = new("persona1", 1);

            List<Persona> list = new List<Persona>();
            list.Add(p1);

            Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(p1)); //true
            Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(p2)); //false
        }
    }
    public class Persona
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Persona(string name, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }
    }
```

En el ejemplo anterior, p1 es verdadero porque tanto él como el contenido de la lista apuntan al mismo espacio en memoria. p2 es falso, porque aunque tenga los mismos valores en sus propiedades, no apunta al mismo objeto.

Por otro lado, si en vez de ser una clase fuera una estructura:

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Persona p1 = new("persona1", 1);
            Persona p2 = new("persona1", 1);

            List<Persona> list = new List<Persona>();
            list.Add(p1);

            Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(p1)); //true
            Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(p2)); //true
        }
    }
    public struct Persona
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Persona(string name, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Acá ambos valores son verdaderos, porque las estructuras las compara por valor

¿Pero qué pasa si es necesario ocupar una clase?

Como Contains busca un objeto igual, habría que redefinir "cuando una Persona es igual a otra". Es decir, hacer override a la función Equals. Por ejemplo, vamos a definir que una persona es igual a otra, cuando su Id es el mismo

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            Persona p1 = new("persona1", 1);
            Persona p2 = new("persona1", 1);

            List<Persona> list = new List<Persona>();
            list.Add(p1);

            Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(p1)); //true
            Console.WriteLine(list.Contains(p2)); //true
        }
    }
    public class Persona
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Persona(string name, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            var p = obj as Persona;
            if (p != null){
                return p.Id == Id;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Por otro lado, también podrías haber ocupado "Any"

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            Persona p1 = new("persona1", 1);
            Persona p2 = new("persona1", 1);

            List<Persona> list = new List<Persona>();
            list.Add(p1);

            Console.WriteLine(list.Any(a => a.Id == p1.Id)); //true
            Console.WriteLine(list.Any(a => a.Id == p1.Id)); //true
        }
    }
    public class Persona
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Persona(string name, int id)
        {
            Name = name;
            Id = id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que sobreescribas tambien el metodo GetHashCode, esto hace que ambos objetos devuelvan el mismo hash, haciendo que de verdad sean identicos, ya que sino sobreescribes este metodo, los objetos devolveran hash diferentes, o sea para asegurarte que dos objetos sean iguales debes sobreescribir el metodo Equals y ademas el metodo GetHashCode

Comment: @Japv Hice la prueba sobrescribiendo el GetHashCode y no retornaba la igualdad.

Comment: Tienes q sobreescribir los dos

Comment: El hash no asegura la igualdad, ésta queda asegurada con Equals.  Si 2 objetos tienen el mismo hash se le considera el mismo objeto pero en el ámbito de ser clave de un diccionario o tabla hash. No obstante, puedo estar de acuerdo que puede ser buena idea implementarlo, porque un tercero puede hacer la comparación por hash en vez de equals y habría un problema. Pero se cae en otro problema, al generar un hash basado en variables mutables, el objeto ya no sirve como clave de un diccionario que es su propósito, por este motivo considero que lo mejor es cambiar hash solo para objetos inmutables

Answer (score 3):

Ampliando la respuesta de **@Yussef**, para asegurar que dos objetos sean realmente iguales, además de sobrescribir el **método Equals**, también se debe sobrescribir el **método GetHashCode**:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    string hash = id.ToString() + Name;
    return hash.GetHashCode(); 
}
```

Concatenas el id con el nombre y a esta concatenación le aplicas el **método GetHashCode** asegurando de esta forma que los objetos a comparar devuelvan un mismo **hash**.